# Access To All Files (Android 11)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-11

I'm developing an application in Kotlin for Android 11. The application needs to read a file the User copies to the phone and placed in the Download folder. The data in the file will be ingested into the application at a time chosen by the User. Again...the applicaiton does **NOT** create this file. As I understand in Android 11, applications are denied access to files the application does not create. Which seems to me is this case.

I have gotten around this restriction by allowing the User to grant the application access to all files. The below code provides a dialog the User can allow or deny access to all files.

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION
val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.packageName, null)
intent.data = uri
startActivity(intent)
```

I'm thinking there's a better way to give the application access to this file, yes?

Comment: Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and allow the user to choose the file wherever they place it.

Comment: `understand in Android 11, applications are denied access to files the application does not create. ` That is not the whole story. Media files are free. Just let the Camera app take some pictures. Your app has access to them.

Comment: yes, good point about Media files. I should have mentioned that